# Select box not returning expected value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that will display different options depending on the first select box.

If option 1 is selected then a second dropdown will be shown with an option pre selected. If option 2 is selected then a different dropdown with two options will be shown.

The two new dropdowns will have the same ID and name for passing the option through to the backend but it keeps returning wrong values. Here is a 
[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/bibaze/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
<p class="input_title">I will use:</p>
<select name="js-rp-use" class="signup-select  js-rp-use" id="rp-use" class="signup-select">
  <option value="">Select Plan</option>
  <option value="SOLO">Manage my own items</option>
  <option value="OTHER">Manage others items</option>
</select>

<div class="js-rentpro-plan-solo">
  <p class="input_title">System Plan:</p>
  <select name="plan_id" id="plan_id" class="signup-select">
    <option value="-1">Select plan</option>
    <option value="1" selected>Plan Solo</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="js-rentpro-plan-other">
  <p class="input_title">System Plan:</p>
  <select name="plan_id" id="plan_id" class="signup-select">
    <option value="-1">Select plan</option>
    <option value="2">Plan Business</option>
    <option value="3">Plan Max</option>
  </select>
</div>

<br><br><br>
<button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>



// jquery
$("div[class^='js-rentpro-plan-']").hide();

$('.js-rp-use').change(function(){

  $('#js-rp-plan-text, .js-rentpro-plan-solo, .js-rentpro-plan-other').hide();

  if( $(this).val() == 'SOLO' ){
    $('.js-rentpro-plan-solo').show();
  } else if( $(this).val() == 'OTHER' ){
    $('.js-rentpro-plan-other').show();
  } else {
    $('#js-rp-plan-text').show();  
  }

});

$('#submit').click(function(){
   console.log( 'plan id is: ' + $('#plan_id').val() );
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uapc4wjk/2/

Answer (score 0):

ID's must be unique. Instead of using the same id, use class.

The reason for you getting the wrong value is you're using `$('#plan_id').val()` It will return the value for the first match it finds.

**EDIT:**
To get the correct value with the current structure you can use:

```
var vl = $(this).siblings('div:visible').find('select').val()
console.log('plan id is: ' + vl );
```

But I suggest you modify the structure, wrap them in a form, give your select containers same class, so you'll have access to them more easily.

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/0r2soc93/)

your selector will always use the first match, regardless of you using element, class or id. Or using the class you can:

```
$('.signup-select:visible').val()
```

Comment: I had it so the other id is hidden only one was ever shown. I've it changed now to use classes but when I do submit the form I still get the wrong value.

Comment: Well in the jsfiddle I posted I get the correct values. The above code does not use the class so it shouldn't make any difference, unless you've changed the structure, which in that case would be good if you post it so I can have a look.

Comment: If you mean that you've changed it to class and call it like `$('.plan_id').val()` it won't make any difference, you'll still get the value of the first match. (even if it's hidden)

Comment: No im using the post on the back end to get the data. The option two works ok, returning 2 and 3 as expected but option 1 and solo keeps returning -1

Comment: I see it is getting the -1 as the first option on the 2nd (hidden select)

Comment: Are you sending the value for both selections to the server, regardless of which one's visible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77610/discussion-between-samurai-and-pierce-mcgeough).